# extjs grid - how to make column width 100%

Tags: grid, extjs4

The property `width` is a pixel width.

```
{
                xtype: 'grid',
                store: store,
                selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    mode: 'SINGLE'
                }),
                layout: 'fit',
                columns: [
                    {
                        text: "pum",
                        dataIndex: 'SRD_NAME_FL',
                        width: 400
                    }
                ],
                columnLines: true
            }
```

if i have only one column how can i make column width = 100%
or if i have several columns - how to make last column stretch to end of grid?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For ExtJS3, set `forceFit` on the GridPanels `viewConfig`. See: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridView

For ExtJS 4 set `forceFit` directly on the GridPanel: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/-cfg-forceFit and use it in conjunction with `flex` on your columns.

**Example for v4**

```
var p = Ext.Create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    forceFit: true,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: _ll.id,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: false,
        flex: 0, //Will not be resized
        width: 60,
        dataIndex: 'Id'
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: __ll.num,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        flex: 1,
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'number'       
    }
});
```

**Example for v3**

```
var p = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
    },
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: _ll.id,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: false,
        fixed: true, //Will not be resized
        width: 60,
        dataIndex: 'Id'
    }, {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        header: __ll.num,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'number'       
    }
});
```

Comment: If anyone is using ExtJS GridFilters, note that forceFit does not work on columns that are being filtered (and therefore italics and bold text) and sorted (and therefore have an arrow beside it). The column will end up taking 2 lines instead of being resized.

Answer (score 9):

Add  `flex : 1` to the column you want to stretch.

Answer (score 2):

For ExtJS 4, use flex instead of width. If you set flex: 1 and there is only one column, it will take 100% width. If you have two columns and set flex: 1 on both, both will have 50% width.

Flex distributes the available width between the columns by ratio. You may for example say flex: 2 for one column and flex: 1 for two other columns and the result would be that the first one would be twice the width of the other two. You may also use decimal values for flex e.g. 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you have a single column in your grid there is a significant difference between using `items:[{}]` and `items:{}` notation.

In fact this will NOT work as expected (at least in ExtJS 4.2):

```
Ext.define('My.SingleColumnGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: {type: 'someStore'},
    forceFit: true,
    columns: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Something',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'something'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

If you just remove square brackets it will magically start to work as expected (i.e. you will have a single column that extends to fill grid width).

This almost drove me crazy ;-P.

Answer (score -2):

set Flex to 1

```
Column.Flex = 1;
```

Comment: You used an invalid syntax (`flex` is lowercase)